# Testing a portable library between .Net 4.6 and Windows Universal 10.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, portable-class-library

I coded a portable class library that targets `.NET Framework 4.6` and `Windows Universal 10.0`, which uses some `System.Reflection;` methods:

- `Type.GetProperty`
- `PropertyInfo.GetValue`

To test my methods I coded a test library that targets `.NET Framework 4.6`. All the methods that don't use `System.Reflection;` are tested correctly. If, from the test library I call a method that uses one of the methods above, I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose you don't forget to add "Sustem.Reflection.TypeExtensions" in the references of your test project...

Comment: I didn't add it, but why is it building anyway?

Comment: Do you have the portable library project and the test project in the same solution ?

Comment: If you have a FileNotFoundException, it's because you're trying to open a file or load an assembly somewhere. So you should try to find what's throwing this exception.